# My Centos 6.4 doesn't accept dns requests

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, iptables, bind

I've a problem with my dns server on my new installed centos 6.4 system. I went though tutorials, try configurations of iptables but can't find a solution.
I've installed bind, created a config file for my domain, restarted named services, but when I hit my domain on a browser, I get 'unable to resolve domain name.
Here is my iptables configuration :

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

The output of the command "iptables -vnL | grep 53" :

```
529 39514 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:53
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:53
0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
152 10920 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
```

the
     netstat -ntupl
command outputs :

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State         PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3429/php fpm
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3414/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3308/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3497/perl
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3936/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3064/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3936/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3414/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2812              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3462/monit
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      3605/httpd
tcp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                        LISTEN      3936/named
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      3064/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      3936/named
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      3605/httpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               3936/named
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:783                 0.0.0.0:*                               2934/portreserve
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                               3497/perl
udp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                                    3936/named
```

I don't know how solve this problem. Does someone have any idea or any suggetion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your bind configuration working correctly? Try 'dig @local YOUR.FQDN' to ensure that bind is running fine.

Comment: Your firewall looks fine. The problem is almost certainly not there.

Comment: Turn off your firewall (`service iptables stop`).  If it's still not working, then the immediate problem is not the firewall.  Don't forget to turn it back on after your test (`service iptables start`).

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the output of `netstat -ntupl`? This will show the listening TCP and UDP sockets so we can verify bind / named is in fact listening for requests.

Comment: You're listening on the loopback addresses. Bind to specific ip or 0.0.0.0/:: and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Iain's answer pushed me in the right direction.

In my instance, was using Bind and the named.conf was lacking the following changes:

- Listening on the external interface (which can be explicitly defined, as opposed to the 'any' wildcard)
- Allowing queries from the local network; e.g. `allow-query     { 192.168.1.0/24; };`

Comment: So does this solve your problem?

Comment: In my instance, yes. Named was serving requests locally, but remotely there was nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not listening on your external address. You are currently listening only on

`127.0.0.1:53`, `::1:53` for both TCP and UDP as well as `127.0.0.1:953` and `::1:953` on TCP.

these are the IPv4 and IPv6 loopback addresses. You need to configure your `listen-on` directive correctly e.g.

```
listen-on {any;};
```